# On Adjacency Matrix of a Graph with a Cut Vertex and a Bridge

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph. If $v_i$ (resp. $v_iv_j$) is a cut vertex (resp. a bridge) of $G$, what can you say about its adjacency matrix $A(G)$?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what the questions is about, but maybe it is. Let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be the two connected components that would form when $v_i$ (resp. $v_iv_j$) was removed. Sort the vertices so that all $V_1$ comes first, then $v_i$ (resp. $v_iv_j$) and finally $V_2$. How the adjacency matrix looks like?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a graph with two components, you can treat each component as its own graph in terms of the adjacency matrix. One of the most basic results is that the spectrum of $G$ is the spectrum of each of its components. So if I have two disconnected instances $C_{3}$ for my graph, then my eigenvalues are $2$ with multiplicity two, and $-1$ with multiplicity four.

**Edit to expand some on the spectrum:**

Spectra vary upon graphs, so that factors into it. Immediately in the characteristic polynomial, we note that the edge count and triangle count are encoded. We can get this by looking at the cofactors. So the coefficient of $\lambda^{n-2}$ is increased by $1$, as $c_{2} = -|E|$ of the graph. Similarly, we note that $c_{3}$, the coefficient of $\lambda^{n-3} = -2C_{3}$, twice the number of triangles in the graph. That won't change since the edge removed is a cut edge.

We also look at our trace-eigenvalue identity. So $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i} = tr(A) = 0$ on a simple graph. Squaring the adjacency matrix gives the diagonal entries as counting the edges. So $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}^{2} = tr(A^{2}) = 2E$, and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}^{3} = tr(A^{3}) = 6C_{3}$. (I am happy to provide more proof if desired). So we see removing a cut edge will change $tr(A^{2})$ but not $tr(A^{3})$.

Another nice example to look at is the star graph on $n$ vertices. Its spectrum is $\pm \sqrt{n-1}$, each with multiplicity one; and $0$ with multiplicity $n-2$. Interestingly enough, $S_{n} - e$, for some $e \in E(S_{n})$ gives us the characteristic polynomial for $S_{n-1}$.

Removing an edge won't change whether or not the graph is bipartite, so the spectrum will still be symmetric to the origin. This means that $\lambda_{i} = -\lambda_{n-i}$. If $G$ is connected, we only have to check that $\lambda_{1} = -\lambda_{n}$ to determine if $G$ is bipartite. However, if $G$ is not connected (by removal of a cut edge), we have to check the entire spectrum. So this quickly goes from a $\Theta(1)$ operation (given the spectrum) to a $\Theta(n)$ operation.

There are textbooks on spectral graph theory; and given the lack of focus of the question, you can see that it's hard to really focus down. These properties constitute probably 10 pages in the textbook I own on the subject.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be answering the question.

Comment: Obviously when you remove an edge, the obvious thing is that you zero out all the cells where that edge occurred. With a cut edge, you get two components. The question is pretty broad, so aside from the obvious, the spectrum of the adjacency matrix is the easiest property to analyze that provides the most information. Of course, with clarification or direction on the question, I'm happy to expand on what exactly for what the OP is looking.

Comment: I guess my problem is that it's not clear to me how the spectrum of the original graph relates to the spectrum of the components upon deletion of the cut-vertex/bridge. Do you know anything about this? I do agree that the question is a bit too unfocused.

Comment: Spectra varies upon graphs. My response is probably too large for a comment. I'll edit my post to expand some. Let me know if I should expand more.